# Gemarah on Baal Teshuva

Tags: talmud-gemara, baal-teshuva, tzaddikim

In Sefer Chasidim, the author compares Baal Teshuva's to Tzadikim. I have heard that there is a Gemarah that does the same and was wondering if someone could cite that Gemarah.

Comment: This is kind of a vague request. In what way does he compare a Baal Teshuva to a Tzaddik?

Comment: Perhaps you may be interested in Brachot 34b or Sanhedrin 99a

Comment: @DoubleAA I have an English version of the Sefer and the footnote at the bottom of one of the pages(I can't seem to remember what page) says that the author is comparing Baal Teshuva's to Tzadikim. What do those to Gemarahs say?

Comment: @DoubleAA, sounds like an answer.

Comment: @Bochur613 "א"ר יוחנן כל הנביאים כולן לא נתנבאו אלא לבעלי תשובה אבל צדיקים גמורים עין לא ראתה אלהים זולתך ופליגא דר' אבהו דא"ר אבהו מקום שבעלי תשובה עומדין צדיקים גמורים אינם עומדין שנאמר (ישעיהו נז) שלום שלום לרחוק ולקרוב לרחוק ברישא והדר לקרוב ורבי יוחנן אמר לך מאי רחוק שהיה רחוק מדבר עבירה מעיקרא ומאי קרוב שהיה קרוב לדבר עבירה ונתרחק ממנו". So both types of people are destined for a great reward, but there is a *machlokes* regarding who is destined for a greater reward.

Comment: Converted comments from @DoubleAA and Fred into an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Gemara ([Berachot 34B](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=34b&format=text), [Sanhedrin 99A](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=24&daf=99&format=text)) states in the name of Rav Abahu that "in the place where Masters of Repentance ("Ba'alei Teshuva") stand, even complete and utter Tzaddikim do not stand":

> במקום שבעלי תשובה עומדין צדיקים גמורים אינם עומדין